# Unable to delete kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, yahoo-kafka-manager

I am using kafka, zookeeper and kafka-manager for managing clusters.

I have 3 nodes cluster. In all the cluster I set since very beginning `delete.topic.enable=true`

Now when I want to delete a topic it is showing following error.

`topicxyz - marked for deletion`

but it is not deleted.

I tried to delete from kafka-manager also and it says

`Yikes! KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /admin/delete_topics/topicxyz`

Error logs:

**kafka-manager**:

```
[ESC[31merrorESC[0m] k.m.ApiError$ - error : KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /admin/delete_topics/topicxyz
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /admin/delete_topics/topicxyz
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:119) ~[org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:783) ~[org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:721) ~[org.apache.curator.curator-framework-2.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:704) ~[org.apache.curator.curator-framework-2.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:108) ~[org.apache.curator.curator-client-2.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:701) ~[org.apache.curator.curator-framework-2.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:477) ~[org.apache.curator.curator-framework-2.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[org.apache.curator.curator-framework-2.10.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:447) ~[org.apache.curator.curator-framework-2.10.0.jar:na]
[ESC[37minfoESC[0m] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Updating internal state...
```

**kafka** has no error log. **zookeeper** stdout errorlog says only warning and stderr log says `Invalid config, exiting abnormally`

**kafka-version**:  kafka_2.12-0.10.2.0

**Topic description**:

```
 $ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topicxyz
Topic:topicxyz  PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: topicxyz Partition: 0    Leader: -1  Replicas: 3 Isr:
```

Please help.

Comment: The command only marks the topic as "to-be-deleted" state. Once it's done, controller should be informed and get started with the deletion. So you could wait a while to see if the topic is deleted completely. Besides, you could also run `kafka-topics --describe` to check the state of topic.

Comment: `$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topicxyz`

`topic: topicxyz PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:`

 `Topic: topicxyz Partition: 0 Leader: -1 Replicas: 2 Isr:`

Comment: I have waited a lot but it seems this is not gonna work.

Comment: Are you sure that after topic is deleted it's not recreated straightaway by some application which writes to that topic?

Comment: No, this is not the case. I fixed above problem by enabling active offset cache from kafka-manager. But Today again the same problem.

Comment: Which version of Kafka are you using?

Comment: kafka_2.12-0.10.2.0

Comment: Do you have this problem for a single topic(topicxyz) or for all topics???

Comment: Not all but few topics.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which kafka version are you using. But deleting a topic had a bug previously. Refer [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1397) & [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2937).

Comment: I am using  kafka_2.12-0.10.2.0

Comment: Then definitely it must be a bug, Raise it in [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4162?jql=fixVersion%20%3D%200.10.0.2%20AND%20project%20%3D%20KAFKA) with logs and steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes caused by a corrupt ZooKeeper node found within `/admin/delete_topics`. Log into the ZK client and delete the misbehaving `/admin/delete_topics/your_topic_name` entry.
Depending on client version it will go something like this:

`bin/zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181
ls /admin/delete_topics
ls /brokers/topics
rmr /admin/delete_topics/your_topic_name`

You should now be able to use Kafka Manager or Kafka-topics to delete your topics. You can also manually remove your topic by deleting the "/brokers/topics/your_topic_name" entry but I find that is unnecessary after removing the misbehaving "delete_topics" entry.